# SQL ORACLE - BOM explosion with duplicated lines - start with...connected by prior...order sibling by

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, connect-by

Could you please support me to identify how to remove duplication in BOM explosion done by statement `start with ... connected by prior...order sibling by` due to Child item repeated in BOM structure itself ?

The starting table `"BOM_table"` is a not-ordered list with columns:

- BOM_LEVEL
- CHILD
- PARENT

where I know the CHILD at first level (renamed CHILD_LVL1 for this discussion)

In std case i have good result using SQL statement

```
select *
from BOM_table
start with CHILD = CHLD_LVL1
Connect by prior CHILD = PARENT
Order sibling by CHILD
```

The result is a table with correct order of CHILD based on LVL relationship

BUT 
I have same case where the CHILD item is present in different BOM point with same PARENT.

For example I have in BOM #2 PARENT with same code and WITH #1 CHILD each with same code. The result of mentioned SQL statement is that for each of these PARENT I have #2 CHILD linked with a total of #4 CHILD

Comment: Take a look at [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause for explosions is a badly formed START WITH / CONNECT BY clause.  Here's an extract from an article I wrote on it.  It assumes we're starting with the standard 14 rows in SCOTT.EMP

Filtering versus Navigation

The definition of how to navigate the hierarchy is quite distinct from the filtering that comes with WHERE clause predicates in the SQL. To demonstrate this, the 14 rows in the EMP table have been duplicated to be a set of rows for multiple geographic regions as shown in Listing 7. There are now 42 rows in the table, the standard set of 14 rows replicated twice for EAST, NORTH and SOUTH regions.

```
Listing 7

SQL> alter table emp add region varchar2(10);

Table altered.

SQL> update emp set region = 'NORTH';

14 rows updated.

SQL>
SQL> insert into emp
  2  select
  3    empno, ename, job, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm, deptno,
  4    decode(r,1,'SOUTH',2,'EAST') region
  5  from emp,
  6       ( select rownum r from dual connect by level <= 2 )
  7  where region = 'NORTH';

28 rows created.

SQL>
SQL> select region, count(*)
  2  from   emp
  3  group by region;

REGION       COUNT(*)
---------- ----------
NORTH              14
SOUTH              14
EAST               14
```

Let's assume a requirement of obtaining the hierarchy for the 14 rows for just the NORTH region.  It would seem intuitive to use the identical query as seen in Listing 2 but with an additional predicate to restrict the REGION to NORTH.  Listing 8 shows the result.

```
Listing 8
SQL> select empno, rpad(' ',level*3)||ename ename, mgr
  2  from   emp
  3  where  region = 'NORTH'
  4  connect by prior empno = mgr
  5  start  with mgr is null;

     EMPNO ENAME                                           MGR
---------- ---------------------------------------- ----------
      7839    KING
      7566       JONES                                    7839
      7788          SCOTT                                 7566
      7876             ADAMS                              7788
      ...
      ...
      7782       CLARK                                    7839
      7934          MILLER                                7782
      7934          MILLER                                7782
      7934          MILLER                                7782

136 rows selected.
```

Notice that the output returned is not 14 rows but 136 rows, even though a predicate to restrict the results to just the NORTH region was applied.

To understand the cause of this problem, consider the very first NORTH region row that is being processed. The START WITH clause is MANAGER IS NULL, so three King rows, one for each region, will belocated, and then the CONNECT BY operation will commence. The CONNECT BY clause is PRIOR EMPNO = MANAGER, so for each KING record , three related employees, one for each region, will be connected to, which rapidly increases the number of rows returned as th query traverses throughout the hierarchy. Only once the hierarchy relationship is established is the WHERE clause predicate applied, so even though the resultset only contains rows for REGION= NORTH, a large amount of redundant work has performed doing erroneous connections to the other regions because CONNECT BY syntax and START WITH syntax did not

• restrict themselves to starting with only the NORTH region, and

• did not make sure that when connecting to the next entry in the hierarchy,

that the row maps from the same region to the subsequent row's region.

Listing 9 shows the corrected syntax for this query. It starts with managers that are null but also only in the NORTH region. It then ensures that when connecting from one manager to a subsequent employee, the definition of connecting also includes a common region. This is synonymous to the way the ANSI join syntax is processed, namely, there is a distinct difference between the hierarchical connecting condition and the WHERE clause predicates that will be applied subsequently as filters.

This gives rise to a common correct criticism of hierarchy queries, that they are running too slowly or consume too many resources. Commonly the cause is that the CONNECT BY information is incomplete, yielding far many more rows being processed than need to be.

```
Listing 9
SQL> select empno, rpad(' ',level*3)||ename ename, mgr
  2  from   emp
  3  connect by prior empno = mgr
  4         and  region = 'NORTH'
  5  start  with mgr is null
  6         and  region = 'NORTH';

     EMPNO ENAME                                           MGR
---------- ---------------------------------------- ----------
      7839    KING
      7566       JONES                                    7839
      7788          SCOTT                                 7566
      7876             ADAMS                              7788
      7902          FORD                                  7566
      7369             SMITH                              7902
      7698       BLAKE                                    7839
      7499          ALLEN                                 7698
      7521          WARD                                  7698
      7654          MARTIN                                7698
      7844          TURNER                                7698
      7900          JAMES                                 7698
      7782       CLARK                                    7839
      7934          MILLER                                7782

14 rows selected.
```

You might ask "What then is the use of a WHERE clause in a hierarchical query?"  The presence of a WHERE clause is still valid, not to define the hierarchy, but to define filtering of the data.  For example, once the NORTH region hierarchy has been instantiated, the requirement might be to only those included employees above a certain SALARY.

Comment: Thanks for prompt  reply.  
Referring to your example my issue is that in same region 'north' , i have same person 'Martin' having as manager both 'Blake' and 'Jones'.
It means Martin is considered part of two separate working Team for a specific brainstorm meeting... 

in my bom case it's for example a minor common item (screw ) part of different items (drawer) that are part of the same King item (forniture)

Comment: In that case, you might need to look at CONNECT BY NOCYCLE